# Create phone and call friends in roblox studio

Tags: lua, roblox

Hello I would like to know if someone knows how it would be possible to create a phone to call friends, for example you see the list of people connected on the phone and call one and when he answers you can have a private chat with him..

Any ideas or way to do this? I've looked everywhere and can't find a solution..

Comment: what are you looking for? it is unlikely that you'll find a tutorial on how to use implement a phone in roblox. break your problems down into atomic steps.

Comment: Don't think Roblox has built-in VOIP.  Use dedicated software that has that as a feature: Mumble, Discord...  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_VoIP_software

Comment: I say Mumble because I know there was a Minetest plugin to use it in-game.  It's possible you could do something like that, but you'd have to look, or program it yourself  --  https://forum.minetest.net/viewtopic.php?t=21586

Answer (score 0):

first, before we start making a chat function, we're going to need a list of players. Create a frame to be the phone, then add the following local script:

```lua
local frame = script.parent
local plrs = game:GetService("Players")
local plr = plrs.LocalPlayer

for i,v in pairs(plrs) do
    if v.Name ~= plr.Name then
        local optionButton = Instance.new("TextButton")
        optionButton.Text = v.Name
        optionButton.Parent = frame
        optionButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
            --They chose a player to talk to
            --We're going to create a value on the player so we can remember who they're talking to:
            local val = Instance.new("StringValue")
            val.Name = "chattingTo"
            val.Value = v.Name
            val.Parent = plr
        end)
    end
end
```

When they click on that button, we know they want to chat to the player V. You could add in some sort of ringing system so the other player can choose to accept/decline the call, but that isn't important. For the chat, to communicate between players, we're going to need a remove event (called "ChatEvent" under Replicated Storage) and a scrolling frame for the messages to show on.
Make a localscript under the chat frame, with:

```
local rs = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local event = rs:WaitForChild("ChatEvent")

event.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(msg, from)
    local textlabel = Instance.new("TextLabel")
    textlabel.Text = from.Name..": "..msg
    textlabel.Parent = script.Parent
end)
```

The script above will handle showing messages it receives. Now we want to be able to send messages, so add to the bottom of that localscript:

```
local inputBox = script.Parent.myTextBox --obviously change all variables to the route in your game
local sendButton = script.Parent.sendButton
local uis = game:GetService("UserInputService")


function sendChat()
    local msgToSend = inputBox.Text
    local sendTo = game.Players.LocalPlayer.chattingTo.Value
    event:FireServer(sendTo, msgToSend)
    local textlabel = Instance.new("TextLabel")
    textlabel.Text = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name..": "..msg
    textlabel.Parent = script.Parent
end

sendButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(sendChat)
uis.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
     if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.Return then
         sendChat()
     end
end)
```

So now whenever we either click the send button or press our enter/return key, it will fire an event on the server. And when an event on the client is fired by the server, it will add a message to the chat. Now we need to just join them together with the following (server) script:

```
local rs = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local event = rs:WaitForChild("ChatEvent")

event.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(from, to, msg)
    --The variable 'to' is who we want to send it to - but it's a string! so:
    local sendTo = game.Players[to]
    event:FireClient(sendTo, msg, from)
end)
```

And that (should) be it. This would work, but it could face moderation action, as it doesn't use roblox's chat filter, so I recommend you integrate something with that.